# How to get a LDO voltage under 1.1V with lm1117 adj LDO?

Tags: power, ldo

I'd like to get voltage under 1.1v with lm1117-adj in 5v input.
The problem is that I don't know,  is this possible to get what I want the voltage under 1.1v?

## update

This is what I've got exactly the same schematic.

[image]

Comment: What does the datasheet say? If Vout is Vadj + Vref and Vref = 1.25V, what happens when Vadj is grounded?

Comment: Why do you need to use an LM1117? Couldn't you use some other component?

Comment: The circuit you shown in that link is not correct. R1/R2 are connected up wrong (they are essentially a single resistor as they are in parallel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [LM7705](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm7705.pdf) and three tiny ceramic caps to generate a -0.232 volt negative rail and then you'd be able to get down to about +1V.

\$V_{OUT} = V_{REF} (1 + \frac{R_2}{R_1}) - 0.232 +I_{ADG}R_2\$

So for R2 = 0, Vout ~= 1.02V

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmuRY1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where \$R_2 (\Omega) \approx 96.2(V_{OUT} -1.018)\$

---

Or use another type of regulator (what I would suggest if the neg rail isn't otherwise useful).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf) on page 11, it tells how to calculate the output voltage:

$$V_{out} = V_{ref}\left(1 + \frac{R_2}{R_1}\right) + I_{adj}R_2$$

\$V_{ref}\$ is 1.25V (also specified in the datasheet). As a result, unless you can make \$\frac{R_2}{R_1}\$ *negative*, it is not possible to get a voltage lower than \$V_{ref}\$. Clearly both resistors are always positive values, so you can't make it negative.

The only way to get a lower voltage from the LM1117 is to add an additional term to that equation.

$$V_{out} = V_{ref}\left(1 + \frac{R_2}{R_1}\right) + I_{adj}R_2 + V_{o}$$

I will define \$V_o\$ as the voltage at the bottom of \$R_2\$ in the circuit shown on page 11. In that circuit, this is connected to ground, so \$V_o = 0\$ and the equation goes back to how it was. If instead of connecting it to ground, it is connected to some negative supply voltage, then clearly we can reduce the output voltage below \$V_{ref}\$. However for that to work you need a negative supply rail.

Comment: Well, in theory, you can make a impedance negative with some active circuitry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_impedance_converter

Comment: @lucas92 while true, it would still require a negative supply rail. The adjustment pin needs to source current, not sink it.

Answer (score 1):

You can play a little trick on the regulator by taking the lower resistor in the chain a little bit negative so, if you have a supply voltage lower than where the bottom resistor connects to you can reduce the output voltage below the 1.25V limit.

Comment: Would you let me know how to do that?

Comment: Do you have a negative supply on your circuit? If not you need to have one.